# How do I see how much RAM global variables use?

Tags: c++, global-variables, microcontroller, ram, memory-consumption

In C/C++ in the context of microcontroller programming, how can I see how much memory global variables use (not counting new/malloc-allocated data)?

Comment: Take a look at the data segment of your compiled binary, posting the architecture and compiler might help

Comment: See your compiler documentation

Comment: Generally speaking it's the size of your binary image data and BSS segments, unless you have local static variables because those will be included too. However, it depends quite a lot on your system (compiler, linker and CPU).

Comment: Global variables may further request heap in their constructors or at run time, so the question need to be more specific.

Comment: You know Stackoverflow is too draconian when you post a question and the highly specific answer and it is still closed for being "too broad"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gcc to link your executable / firmware, you can add the option `-Map=memory.map` to the command line.

In that file you'll find something like this, which tells you where RAM is:

```
Memory Configuration

Name             Origin             Length             Attributes
FLASH            0x00014000         0x0002c000         xr
RAM              0x20002000         0x00002000         xrw
*default*        0x00000000         0xffffffff
```

Note the address of the RAM (`0x20002000`). Later on you'll find the addresses of your global variables in RAM. The difference in addresses will tell you their size:

```
 .bss           0x20002924       0x94 C:/Users/...../main.cpp.o
                0x20002924                i2c
                0x20002934                ex1
                0x20002948                ex2
                0x2000295c                sensorI2C
                0x20002978                sensorSPI0
                0x2000299c                sdCard
```

The first column (`.bss`) indicates that the we are in the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) where uninitialised global variables are stored. The second column is the address (which by comparing to the above we can see is in RAM. Third column (`0x94`) shows the total size used by `main.cpp`, and the final column gives the source file name & the symbols.

**Note:** Initialised "Plain Old Data" global variables (e.g. `int a = 1;`) will go in the `.data` segment,  so look there too! (Thanks Paul) Variables that are initialised with C++ constructors still go in `.bss`. Check both segments anyway.

Comment: doesn't `bss` just refer to global variables that are unitialised or initialised to 0? and that there's *another* data segment for globals initialised to non-zero values...

Comment: Ah yes you are right - those go in the `.data` segment.